# How to apply last th in table display none?

Tags: css

I have a problem with table th, I can not set display none to the last th.

Here is my code:

```
#content-area-job-details #site-content-job-details .entry-content table.job-table tr th:last-of-type{
display:none;
}
```

when I use this code it set display to none for all th. I want only last th display none.

You can see my problem at:

http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=974

Help me please

Comment: Have you tried assigning a class programatically to the desired th and adding that class to the display:none style?

Comment: this is plugin I can not add class, I can only inspec element and style bro

Comment: IT IS A TRAP ;-) Master of Web-Developer :-D

Comment: Maybe remove your verry last tr and go to tr:last-child>th

Comment: I think what you looking for is a colspan... you doint want 2 columns in last point. am i right ? so maybe use a text-indent: -22222px or like that to hide only the text

Comment: Oh bro I want only last th display none

Comment: http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=974

Comment: if your html structure doesn't change, you can use this  `#content-area-job-details #site-content-job-details .entry-content table.job-table tr:nth-last-child(2) th`

Comment: yes its work for me bro very thz q :D

Comment: now post ur answer bro

Comment: My goal is to help people, not earn reputation, I think you should give upvote at least to @poke because he explain it for you.

Comment: I am very very thz q again bro :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn’t work that way. `:last-child` or `:last-of-type` are always relative to the parent container. So in case of a table, that’s the `tr` element. If you match all `tr` elements in the table, and then get the last `th` for each, then you are matching every last `th` in each of those rows. So in your case, essentially all `th`s.

You would need to have a way to select that one `tr` which you are interested in, but other than maybe `:nth-last-child(2)`, there is not really a good way to get that one. You should add an actual class to it.

Note that just hiding the `th` will not give you the desired result though. Table cells are always table cells, and unless you make them take more than a single cell, they will only ever occupy a single cell. So in your case, if you hide or remove that one `th`, the following `td` will *not* fill the whole row. It will only fit that very small cell where the `th` was previously located. You would have to add `colspan="2"` to the td *in the markup* to fix that.

Comment: @user307709 The point of my answer was to tell you that it doesn’t work. You cannot solve this using CSS alone.

Comment: Funnily enough, the `colspan="2"` attribute is not needed in this example, at least not in Firefox 42 (that's all I could check before the user changed the page to his needs). For some reason, the `<pre>` elements (and only those) expanded to the whole width of the table. But of course, the colspan attribute should be added.

Comment: @Gabrielmachts The `pre` tag overflows the boundaries of the cell, but that doesn’t mean that the cell is bigger. If you look at the top of the cell, you can see that that underlined heading is only as wide as the other `th`s.

Comment: @poke That's what I said. In other words... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should use javascript to do what you need...

```js
(function(window) {
  'use strict';
  
  function hideLastTh() {
    var lastElement;
    
    try {
      lastElement = window
        .document
        .querySelector('.job_info')
        .parentElement
        .parentElement
        .querySelector('th[scope="row"]')
      ;
      
      lastElement
        .classList
        .add('hidden')
      ;
      
    } catch(e) {
      console.error('hideLastTh:ERROR', e);
    }
    
  
  }
  
  return window.document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', hideLastTh);
})(window);
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see that your site uses jQuery. If you can add jQuery code, just add these two lines:

```
$("th:last").hide();
$("th:last").siblings("td").attr("colspan","2");
```